# Select2 Placeholder becomes invisible when we bind something using [(ngModel)]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jquery-select2

I've the below angular code in my project application where in which the `select2` is not getting initialized with a placeholder text when the `[(ngModel)]` value is coming empty.

```
<app-select2 [(ngModel)]="value" placeholder="place_holder_text" class="form-control" (blur)="onBlur()">
    <template [ngIf]="item.name">{{ item.name }}</template>
<app-select2>
```

I've searched across `select2` related posts regarding this bug, but no luck when it comes to finding any solution (or) workaround.

Hence I would like to know whether we can make the `[(ngModel])` to be enclosed within a `if` condition, I admit that this approach might appear silly, but I've no other go because the `<app-select2>` is a component (wrapper for select2) which I'm not allowed to edit

Can someone help?

Comment: Placeholder is just for display.

Comment: Yes,  I agree...And that display is not happening in my case...

Comment: so what is happening? What do you see?

Comment: Select2 is getting initialized without the placeholder text

Comment: Have you tried to remove the ngModel and see if the placeholder works ? Maybe the problem isn't related to the NgModel

Comment: @AlexyHody I tried and the placeholder text is indeed appearing..